# Как расшарить буфер обмена между ОС внутри виртуалки VirtualBox и основной ОС?

Tags: virtualbox

Сижу на Windows, в VirtualBox установлена Ubuntu. Понадобилось скопировать вывод консоли из Ubuntu и вставить кое-куда в Windows. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: общий буффер обмена

Comment: Ответ мне лень оформлять, но для каждой ОС есть гостевые дополнения. Для Ubuntu они имеются. Подробная инструкция дана [здесь](https://www.zachpfeffer.com/single-post/2017/02/18/Enabling-copying-and-pasting-text-between-an-Ubuntu-16042-guest-running-in-Oracle-VM-VirtualBox-5114-running-on-Windows-7-and-the-Windows-7-host)